Blazor Client Side Validation
I am trying a pure client side validation without invoking any SignalR Connection in Blazor Web App.
I am using this code where signalr is invoked due to Interactive Server type render. On removing it the page keeps reloading on submit: -
Command line: -
dotnet new blazor

Code: -
@page "/pure"
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<EditForm Model="_login" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" FormName="LoginForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText @bind-Value="_login.UserName" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="_login.Password" type="password" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Login _login = new Login();

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // Perform any async tasks here
        Console.WriteLine($"Submit clicked - no reloading: User name is {_login.UserName} and password is {_login.Password}");

        // Optional: Simulate async operation
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    public class Login
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is required")]
        public string? UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string? Password { get; set; }
    }
}


On Blazor Web Assembly this code works perfect with no SignalR connection invoked.Help me to integrate the same in the above code
Command line: -
dotnet new blazorwasm

Web Assembly Code: -
@page "/custom"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<EditForm Model="_login" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText @bind-Value="_login.UserName" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="_login.Password" type="password" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Login _login = new Login();

    private async Task Submit()
    {
        // Display in console or do some action to verify it's not reloading
        Console.WriteLine($"User name is {_login.UserName} and password is {_login.Password}");
    }

    public class Login
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is required")]
        public string? UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string? Password { get; set; }
    }
}


I tried wasm but need to integrate the same effect in web app.

dotnet new blazor defaults to blazor server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates. Did you add Webassembly support?  Maybe add --interactivity Auto or --interactivity Webassembly
